# How to set onclicklistener of different layout button

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

i am working in android .where i created one list view and each row of list view contain two edit text fields and two buttons ,now i want on set onclicklistener on the button,but i am getting error.so can you help on this...

***installation.java***

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_installation);
        Datalist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.installationList);

        ButtonLayout ViewButton=new ButtonLayout();


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hashMap");


       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Installation.this, arl,
                R.layout.activity_button_layout, new String[]
                        {   
                        TAG_Title,TAG_URL 
                         }, new int[] { 
                        R.id.InnerText1,R.id.URL1 });

        Datalist.setAdapter(adapter);




        ViewButton.ClickButton = (ImageButton)activity_button_layout.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton011);

         ViewButton.ClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "*********");
              }
            });
```

i am getting error that **activity_button_layout cannot be resolved**.when i am using it `ViewButton.ClickButton = (ImageButton)activity_button_layout.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton011);`

***activity_button_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget36"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listbackground"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/widget37"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_x="275dp"
    android:layout_y="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/InnerText1"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="8dp"
    android:layout_y="9dp"
    android:background="#07000000"
    android:text=" "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton011"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_x="315dp"
    android:layout_y="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="clickImage"
    android:src="@drawable/viewdoc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/URL1"
    android:layout_width="241dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="6dp"
    android:layout_y="38dp"
    android:textColor="#ff5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

***ButtonLayout.java***

```
private static final String TAG_InnerText = "InnerText";
    private static final String TAG_Title = "Title";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "URL";


   public ImageButton ClickButton=null;
    EditText   EditURL=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button_layout);
    }
```

Comment: this is complie time error right? hv u declared activity_button_layout?

Comment: where you initial activity_button_layout

Comment: yes...It is working correctly on  ViewButton.ClickButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton011);   but when it reached at onclick listener then my activity was stopping.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton011);

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "*********");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your adapter

```
ViewButton.ClickButton = (ImageButton)activity_button_layout.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton011);

     ViewButton.ClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View view) {
          Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "*********");
          }
        });
```

Comment: Have you used          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View activity_button_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_button_layout,
    container, false);
         in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

R.layout.activity_button_layout is an ID of a resource defined in R.xml, not a reference to a created view of any kind, so trying to use activity_button_layout as such will have little sense.

Instead, you should override the getView() method from your SimpleAdapter, and after inflating a single list item, attach the onClickListener to the desired subview.